# FILESTREAM files being left behind after row deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, blob, filestream

I have successfully set up FILESTREAM on my SQL 2008 server; however I've noticed that even when I have deleted rows containing FILESTREAM data, the physical data file doesn't seem to get deleted.

By the physical file, I mean the file in SQLServer's managed directory with a uniqueidentifer as the filename not the original file added to the dbase.

Does anyone know if SQLServer will delete the file eventually? If there are a lot of large files removed from the dbase I'd expect to be able to reclaim the space quickly that's all.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`FILESTREAM` data is subject to transaction control and therefore is not deleted instantly.

Instead, `SQL Server` runs a garbage collector which purges the old data when it is sure it had been ultimately deleted.

From the [**documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109.aspx):

> `FILESTREAM` garbage collection is a background task that is triggered by the database checkpoint process. A checkpoint is automatically run when enough transaction log has been generated. For more information, see the **SQL Server 2008 Books Online** topic “`CHECKPOINT` and the Active Portion of the Log” (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189573.aspx). Given that `FILESTREAM` file operations are minimally logged in the database’s transaction log, it may take a while before the number of transaction log records generated triggers a checkpoint process and garbage collection occurs. If this becomes a problem, you can force garbage collection by using the `CHECKPOINT`statement.

Answer (score 15):

use

```
sp_filestream_force_garbage_collection
```

unfortunately this only works >= SQL Server 2012

Comment: FYI - This is only for SQL 2012

Comment: Yes thanks. I also need that. One good reason to upgrade to 2012!

Comment: I tried this on my local SQL Server 2012 Express and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: if you want this to start working immediatly, call it twice, it will then start removing files in the background. can take a long while depending of the number of files

Comment: @corix010 If it doesn't work check the recovery mode of your DB. If it is full, change it to Simple and then run the command again. It will work

Answer (score 5):

First you have to create a [Checkpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/database-checkpoints-sql-server) for the [Garbage Collector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/filestream-and-filetable-sp-filestream-force-garbage-collection) work. After you Deleted rows you can run this code to eliminate all files that don't belong to any row.

```
USE [DataBaseName]
GO

-- Create a checkpoint on current database
CHECKPOINT
GO 

-- Execute Garbage Collector after a checkpoint created
EXEC sp_filestream_force_garbage_collection  'DataBaseName'
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

DELETE FROM tbl_XXX DECLARE @test CHECKPOINT @test = 0

Run this in your sql server 
and You can observe the file getting deleted from file system also..

You can set the the number of minutes or seconds to wait for the garbage collector to clean up the files from filesystem after performing the deletion operation.

Thanks

haranath

Comment: easier: DELETE FROM table CHECKPOINT

Comment: @DanDan I know this is like years ago but I just want to warn other users about the danger of accidentally deleting all rows in your table when `DELETE FROM table CHECKPOINT` command is used. I tried it and it deleted all rows in my table. Fortunately my table just contains sample data.